# How to use a Web worker with Mediapipe Vision

Tags: javascript, web-worker, mediapipe

I'm developing a game that uses hand detection

I'm attempting use Web workers so that hand detection doesn't block the main thread as per [mediapipe docs](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/hand_landmarker/web_js)

I'm wondering if anyone is able to produce an example as to how this would be done.

the `detectForVideo` method takes two params, a reference to the dom element and a timestamp.

Since Web Workers can't [access dom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#about_thread_safety), I'm getting an error.

This is my code

```js
const worker = new Worker('landmarker/worker');


class UIManager {
  constructor() {
    this.$video = document.getElementById("webcam");
  }

  bindEnableCam() {
//this method is called elsewhere, it attaches the `predictWebcam` method to run once the webcam is ready
        const handleStream = (stream) => {
          this.$video.srcObject = stream;
          this.$video.addEventListener(
            "loadeddata",
            this.predictWebcam.bind(this)
          );
        };

        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia(constraints)
          .then((stream) => handleStream(stream))
  }

  predictWebcam() {
   
    const nowInMs = Date.now();
    worker.postMessage({vid: this.$video}) // this line of code throws the error
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.predictWebcam.bind(this));
    
  }
  
}
```

Produces this error.

```
caught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': HTMLVideoElement object could not be cloned.
    at UIManager.predictWebcam
```

I also get an error if I try to pass the landmarker or `detectForVideo` method

```
UIManager.js?t=1683753166973:81 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': () => o.wasmBinaryPath.toString() could not be cloned.
    at UIManager.predictWebcam
```

Lasty, I tried just sending over a string and running everything from the worker and setting the worker to `{type: "module"}`.

```
//in my worker.js

import handLandmarker from ".";
import { ui } from "../UIManager";

self.onmessage = (e) => {
 
 if(e.data === 'detect'){
  handLandmarker.detectForVideo(ui.$video, Date.now())
 }
}
```

However this now produces this error:

```
vision_bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Module scripts don't support importScripts().
    at o (vision_bundle.js:1:466026)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at r (vision_bundle.js:1:466152)
    at createTaskRunner (vision_bundle.js:1:467669)
    at TaskRunner.createInstance (vision_bundle.js:1:467909)
    at VisionTaskRunner.createVisionInstance (vision_bundle.js:1:472322)
    at b.createFromOptions (vision_bundle.js:1:553534)
    at index.js:9:45
o
```

This one seems to be a problem with workers not fully supporting modules, however I can't think of how I'd get around that when I have to import the `HandLandmarker` and `FilesetResolver` from the vision package

Comment: For the first part I can help: the `HTMLVideoElement` is not a transferable object, as in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects and so you need to call something like `createImageBitmap` and transfer that. However I'm also hitting the importScripts error when trying to run inference in a worker, and it seems unsupported, for now.

Comment: I've now resolved this for a different task (FaceLandmarker), but it isn't pretty. It isn't in a state to post as a full answer, at this time. So in brief: vendor the code to create the task class, replace the call to `importScripts` with `await import(script).then(({ default: f }) => (self.ModuleFactory = f));`, and fix whatever follows. This works in chrome, at least, though I'm not sure it should, as I believe dynamic import _shouldn't_ work in workers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send individual video stream frames to the worker.
For performance purposes, you want to [**transfer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Transferable_objects) them to the worker as @David Baynard commented. There are several ways to capture and transfer a video frame, so you will have to choose one that works in your desired environment (not all browsers support certain APIs like VideoFrame, MediaStreamTrackProcessor, etc...).

A common way is to draw frames on an [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) and create an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) object from the most recently rendered image of the OffscreenCanvas.

Your code could look like this:

```
class UIManager {
  constructor() {
    this.$video = document.getElementById("webcam");
  }

  $offCanvas = null;
  $offContext = null;

  bindEnableCam() {
//this method is called elsewhere, it attaches the `predictWebcam` method to run once the webcam is ready
        const handleStream = (stream) => {
          this.$video.srcObject = stream;
          this.$video.addEventListener(
            "loadeddata",
            this.predictWebcam.bind(this)
          );

          this.$offCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(this.$video.videoWidth, this.$video.videoHeight);
            this.$offContext = this.$offCanvas.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });
        };


        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia(constraints)
          .then((stream) => handleStream(stream))
  }

  predictWebcam() {
   
    const nowInMs = Date.now();
    const imageBitmap = this.getRecentFrame();
    worker.postMessage({ task: 'detectHand', frame: imageBitmap }, [imageBitmap])
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.predictWebcam.bind(this));
    
  }

  getRecentFrame() {
    this.$offContext.drawImage(this.$video, 0, 0);
    return offscreenCanvas.transferToImageBitmap();
  }
}
```